# ColdFusion web.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, coldfusion

Is there a ColdFusion analog for the deployment descriptor/web.xml file found in a J2EE web container? I know CF is running on top of JRun and that I could just tweak the JRun dd, but what about an application-specific configuration file? Is there something like this that I'm not aware of or do you just have to roll your own?

Comment: Could you provide information on what behaviors you are trying to emulate?  It would help us answer the question more accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion 8 has several application-specific configurations that can be set in the application.cfc file

application.cfc also implements several "general events" which occur during application execution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using an app.cfc but I'm looking for the something that gives me the declarative-ness that web.xml or (web.config ala .ne-e-e-et)

Answer (score 2):

There are several areas that equivalent settings

`application.cfc` or on older sites `application.cfm`

CFAdmin tool has some more settings for Datasources, JVM, etc

Depending on the framework you use, there may be additional .xml configuration files.

Fusebox uses: files called `fusebox.xml` and `circuit.xml`

FW/1 uses additional settings in `application.cfc`

Answer (score 1):

You might check this posting on Application.cfc http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-Tutorial-And-Application-cfc-Reference.htm.

And if you are not using a version of Coldfusion that has Application.cfc available you will need to look into Application.cfm which is implemented quite a bit differently then Application.cfc.

Answer (score 1):

there is a jrun.xml file that allows for some configuration. It is available in CF7 and CF8. I have only done small tweaks to this file e.g. bind ip address to CF instance.

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion provides client and server deployment descriptor files located in \ColdFusion8\wwwroot\WEB-INF. The files are client-config.wsdd and server-config.wsdd respectfully